# An Error when Importing "mp3play" plugin

Tags: python

I downloaded mp3play from pip.But,when I try to import it,it gives me that error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/semih/Desktop/hata.py", line 1, in <module>
import mp3play
File "C:\Users\semih\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\mp3play\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
from .windows import AudioClip as _PlatformSpecificAudioClip
File "C:\Users\semih\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\mp3play\windows.py", line 27
print 'Error %s for "%s": %s' % (str(err), txt, buf)
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can someone help me please?Thanks!

Comment: Your library is written for Python2 but you're running Python3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your library is for Python 2, but you're trying to use it in Python 3.

Search another library that can do the same thing, search if there's a Python 3 version or use it in Python 2.

Comment: Do you know a library that I can play mp3 files in Python 3?

Comment: If you're in windows, you can try `winsound`, it's preinstalled in Python

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, the version on PyPi was not meant for use in python3 (it was published in 2008). However, if you follow the link to the sourcecode, you end up [at this git repo](https://github.com/michaelgundlach/mp3play). There was a [commit](https://github.com/michaelgundlach/mp3play/commit/5c4ba92ea0244ca73e5273aa798914ee5c644f6c) 4 years ago that fixed python3 support, but that version was never uploaded to pypi.

What you can do is:

1. Download/clone the git
2. run `python setup.py` to install the package
3. enjoy!